# unable to initiate angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui

i'm trying to initiate google map by using [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)
however, i'm having these errors, although i have followed the guide on the [quickstart](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use) page

[image]
so i google the error but i got nothing, but i saw some similar issues and it caused by AdBlock, so i use an incognito windows to test again,these errors are gone but the google map still not on my app

here's my full code

**master.html**(contain all the src)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/lodash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/satellizer/0.9.4/satellizer.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/loading-bar.js"></script>
```

**app.js[angular.js]**

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngMaterial','ngSanitize','ngAnimate','satellizer','ngResource','ui.router','ngMessages','angular-loading-bar','uiGmapgoogle-maps']).
 config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$authProvider','$locationProvider','$mdThemingProvider','cfpLoadingBarProvider','uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$authProvider,$locationProvider,$mdThemingProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
     uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //    key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
     $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/static/views/index.html',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
  })
.
.
.
```

**controller.js[angular.js]**

```
angular.module('app').controller('IndexCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$http',
  '$rootScope',
  '$auth',
  'Account',
  'uiGmapGoogleMapApi',
  function ($scope, $http, $rootScope,$auth,Account,uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
      $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };


    });
  }
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
    {{map.center}}  
    </div>
```

the {{map.center}} is able to display but not the map.

Comment: is that "blocked by client" errror still present without an adblocker?

Comment: @campino2k hi, no the blocked by client error is gone as what i stated on the question(there's no error or anything on the console), however i still not able to get the google map display on my app.

Comment: Have you added height and width to the map?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not initiated basic GoogleMap API

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need "bootstraping" the Google Maps API. I usually use this in my HTML instead of use `ng-app`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Manually  bootstrapping method instead of ng-app="myApp" to be sure
  // Google API Library is downloaded before Angular compiles the root page "/"
  function onGoogleReady() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, [ 'myApp' ]);
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&callback=onGoogleReady";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  window.onload = loadScript();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm just guessing here but have you tried this way?

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='{{map.center}}' zoom='{{map.zoom}}'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: did you put something like this in your css?

.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }